App doesn't redirect after 3dscan was accepted in ios
I have a problem with my IOS App. I have a pwa and use flutter_inappwebview to create an iOS app. I use adyen for payments in my app, but it's stuck after I accept the 3dsecure in my banking app. The problem exists only for IOS app if I open my pwa in safari, chrome or the android the payment works just fine.
My WebviewSettings:
InAppWebViewSettings settings = InAppWebViewSettings(
    transparentBackground: true,
    supportZoom: false,
    useOnDownloadStart: true,
    useShouldOverrideUrlLoading: true,
    mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture: false,
    useShouldInterceptAjaxRequest: true,
    javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically: true,
    supportMultipleWindows: true,
    useHybridComposition: true,
    allowsLinkPreview: false,
    useOnNavigationResponse: false,
    suppressesIncrementalRendering: false,
    enableViewportScale: true,
    disallowOverScroll: true,
    allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures: false,
    allowsInlineMediaPlayback: true,
  );

pubspec.lock:
dependencies:
    flutter:
        sdk: flutter

    add_2_calendar: ^2.2.3
    flutter_inappwebview: ^6.0.0
    permission_handler: ^10.2.0
    path_provider: ^2.0.11
    device_info_plus: ^3.0.0
    open_file_safe: ^3.2.3
    url_launcher: ^6.1.7
    gif_view: ^0.3.1
    nfc_manager: ^3.2.0
    firebase_core: ^2.4.1
    notification_permissions: ^0.6.1
    firebase_messaging: ^14.2.1
    app_tracking_transparency: ^2.0.3

When I click on "pay" I get redirected to the 3dsecure page, where I should accept the payment in my app. The redirect works and I can accept it, but nothing happens afterwards.
When I do the same thing in safari, the page does like a refresh every few seconds, this is missing in my app I guess this is the problem? Also I get this error, idk if this has something to do with it?

This is my shouldInterceptAjaxRequest
                            (controller, request) async {
                          List urlListPOST = ["/api/login"];
                          print("AJAX Request Intercepted:");
                          print("URL: ${request.url}");
                          print("Method: ${request.method}");
                          print("Headers: ${request.headers}");
                          if (request.method == 'POST' && urlListPOST.contains(request.url.toString())) {
                            // Set app identifier for vue
                            await _setBasicDeviceInfo(controller);
                            await _checkInternetConnection();
                            if (_isConnected) {
                              print("connected");
                              return request;
                            } else {
                              print("NOT connected");
                              urlPreNoInternet = urlController.text;
                              print("NO INTERNET");
                              print(urlPreNoInternet);
                              controller.loadFile(
                                  assetFilePath: "assets/html/nointernet.html");
                              setState(() {
                                _showSplash = false;
                              });
                            }
                          } else {
                            List urlListGET = [
                              "/api/gf/courses/calendar",
                              "/api/studios/fetch",
                              "/api/videoarchiv",
                              "/api/user",
                              "/api/plan"
                            ];
                            if (request.method == "GET" && urlListGET.contains(request.url.toString())) {
                              await _checkInternetConnection();
                              if (_isConnected) {
                                return request;
                              } else {
                                urlPreNoInternet = urlController.text;
                                controller.loadFile(
                                    assetFilePath: "assets/html/nointernet.html");
                                setState(() {
                                  _showSplash = false;
                                });
                              }
                            } else {
                              return request;
                            }
                          }
                        },

Which loggs:

If you guys need more information please feel free to ask, I'm stuck on this problem for quite some time now.
